# Search in Backbone Collections, Updating UI with React

Tags: javascript, search, backbone.js, reactjs

I'm spending time on something probably simple:
I'd like to implement a search bar, ideally updating the list of item as-you-type. My small app uses React and Backbone (for models and collections).

Displaying the list isn't too hard, it all works perfectly doing this (the mixin i'm using basically allows easy collections retrieval):

```
var List = React.createClass ({

    mixins: [Backbone.React.Component.mixin],

    searchFilter: function () {
        //some filtering code here, not sure how (filter method is only for arrays...)
        }
    }

    getInitialState: function () {
        initialState = this.getCollection().map(function(model) {
            return { 
                    id: model.cid,
                    name: model.get('name'),
                    description: model.get('description')
                    }
        });
        return {
            init: initialState,
            items : []
        }
    },

    componentWillMount: function () {
        this.setState({items: this.state.init})
    },

    render: function(){
        var list = this.state.items.map(function(obj){
            return (
                    <div key={obj.id}>
                        <h2>{obj.name}</h2>
                        <p>{obj.description}</p>
                    </div>      
                )
        });
        return (
            <div className='list'>
            {list}
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Now i've tried with no success to first translate the backbone collection into "state" with the getInitialState method, my idea was to proxy through a copy of the collection, which then could hold the search results. I'm not showing here my attemps for the sake of clarity(edit: yes i am), could someone guide me to the right approach? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your attempt at implementing the search in `getInitialState?` My first thought would be to store the `search` on state (or a prop if it is being passed in by a parent) and filter the collection based on that in your render method.

Comment: I'd agree with @NickTomlin -- if you show some of the code it might be helpful. The `render` function could just perform a live filter whenever a `searchText` property (like `props.searchText`) changes for example.

Comment: Thanks @NickTomlin and @WiredPrairie for the insight,here is what i had for the `getInitialState` method, the item array is supposed to be filtered with the search text 
`getInitialState: function () {
  initialState = this.getCollection().map(function(model) {
   return { 
     id: model.cid,
     name: model.get('name'),
     description: model.get('description'),
     }
  });
  return {
   init: initialState,
   items : []
  }
 }`
But this doesn't really feel right, I feel i should be able to do the searching without passing through react's state concept, and rather use only collections

Comment: @senseye I'd move the code in your comment into the question for readability and clarity. Again, i'd recommend not creating a separate collection. The view is just a "display" of the collection, and you can just replace your `map` with a `filter` and only include the items that match whatever your search criteria is.

Comment: @NickTomlin, i updated the code to include the entire react element, the `searchFilter` method isn't implemented as it took me time to get the rest reasonnably working... As i understand it, you're saying copying the collection into state to store the search is the right approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this, but the simplest (in my opinion) is to store your search criteria in the `List` component's state and use it to filter which items from your collection get displayed. You can use a Backbone collection's built in `filter` method to do this.

```
var List = React.createClass ({

  mixins: [Backbone.React.Component.mixin],
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      nameFilter: ''
    };
  },
  updateSearch: function (event) {
    this.setState({
      nameFilter: event.target.value
    });
  },
  filterItems: function (item) {
    // if we have no filter, pass through
    if (!this.state.nameFilter) return true;
    return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.nameFilter) > -1;
  },
  render: function(){
    var list = this.props.collection
      .filter(this.filterItems.bind(this))
      .map(function(obj){
        return (
          <div key={obj.id}>
            <h2>{obj.name}</h2>
          </div>
        )
    });

    return (
      <div className='list'>
      {list}
        <input onChange={this.updateSearch} type="text" value={this.state.nameFilter}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

var collection = new Backbone.Collection([
  {
    name: 'Bob'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bill'
  },
  {
    name: 'James'
  }
]);

React.render(<List collection={collection}/>, document.body);
```

**jsbin**

The search criteria could easily be passed down from a parent component as a prop, so the search input does not have to live inside your `List` component.

Comment: Thanks! I just found something (i'll post it below), but I like your solution better! Indeed filtering the collection was the thing I missed.

Comment: Thanks, helped me out understanding React better :)

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I also found a different solution (below), but it involves copying the entire collection into state, which is probably not such a good idea...

```
var List = React.createClass ({

    mixins: [Backbone.React.Component.mixin],

    searchFilter: function () {
        var updatedlist = this.state.init;
        var searchText = this.refs.searchbar.getDOMNode().value
        updatedlist = updatedlist.filter(function (item) {
            return  item.name.toLowerCase().search(
                searchText.toLowerCase()) !== -1
        });
        this.setState({items: updatedlist})
        }
    },

    getInitialState: function () {
        initialState = this.getCollection().map(function(model) {
            return { 
                    id: model.cid,
                    name: model.get('name'),
                    description: model.get('description')
                    }
        });
        return {
            init: initialState,
            items : []
        }
    },

    componentWillMount: function () {
        this.setState({items: this.state.init})
    },

    render: function(){
        var list = this.state.items.map(function(obj){
            return (
                    <div key={obj.id}>
                        <h2>{obj.name}</h2>
                        <p>{obj.description}</p>
                    </div>      
                )
        });
        return (
            <div className='list'>
            <input ref='searchbar' type="text" placeholder="Search" onChange={this.searchFilter}/>
            {list}
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```